# Running hcitool to variable uses IFS

Tags: linux, bash

I'm in the middle of writing a config tool for a bluetooth application on Raspberry Pi with Stretch Lite.
When I run `hcitool scan` I see this output:

```
Scanning ...
        00:80:52:51:3D:7E       BlueCN+001 D-513D7E
        84:C7:EA:64:45:87       Xperia X Compact
```

Now I want this output in a variable `scanres`, so I use

```
scanres=$(hcitool scan)
```

This is seems OK, but the mac-address misses the ':'

```
echo $scanres
Scanning ...
        00 80 25 51 3D 7E       BlueCN+001 D-513D7E
        84 C7 EA 64 45 87       Xperia X Compact
```

Somewhere in my script I changed the IFS (Internal Field Separator) without setting it back to the original value.

```
IFS=':'
```

Is this normal behaviour?

I know I can redirect the output to a file with `hcitool scan>scanres` but I want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: `echo "$scanres"`, **in quotes**.

Comment: @anubhava, tsk tsk. If you looked at this one a bit closer, you'd realize that IFS isn't doing *anything at all* during the execution of `hcitool`.

Comment: Yes you're right @CharlesDuffy , deleted my non-sense comment.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. You need to unset the IFS before calling echo

I assumed that xxx has a following content

```
Scanning ...
        00:80:52:51:3D:7E       BlueCN+001 D-513D7E
        84:C7:EA:64:45:87       Xperia X Compact

 IFS=':'
 ( IFS=''  var=$(cat xxx); echo $var; )
 echo "$IFS"
```

In return you will get

```
Scanning ...
        00:80:52:51:3D:7E       BlueCN+001 D-513D7E
        84:C7:EA:64:45:87       Xperia X Compact
```

and IFS is unchanged eq to ':'

Comment: Emptying `IFS` prevents string-splitting, but it doesn't prevent glob expansion -- if your variable contained only the character `*`, then `echo $var` would still print a list of filenames instead of that `*`; if the variable contained `[some string]'` and you had a file named `s`, you'd get the file name printed, etc. The right answer here -- the thing that works in all cases -- is to quote the expansion.

Comment: You are right Charles ! Thanks for clarification :)